# How to get a specific table kind design view in the SF standard functionality

Tags: custom-object, standard-field, standard

I am creating a custom object with all fields using the SF standard functionality, I don't want to use any VF page creation. Using standard functionality, how can I get the following functionality? It might not look same as below (taken from a different system) but can fulfill the needed function with a somewhat good look.

I need to create a field "car accessories" with some multi select values (multi picklist can be created, I know) but I need to put some number values for each selected value. In the example below, if I choose, say, solar firm, I need to put the value of 5000 besides it (or below it) and at last, a field to sum up all inputted values in "car modification sum insured".

[image]